# UnboundLocalError-Python Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

> local variable 'variable' referenced before assignment

Estoy tratando de que mis datos se guarden en el `Admin` de DJANGO.
aquí esta mi fragmento de código, es la view de django:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
#from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from .forms import ComprasForm

# Create your views here.

def compras(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        #se van a resivir los datos que se estan mandando en el POST
        variable=ComprasForm(request.POST)
        #si lo que se resive fue un POST
        if variable.is_valid():
            variable.save() #aqui se guardan

            return redirect('compras:compras')
        else:
            #Cuando sea un metodo 'GET
            variable=ComprasForm()
            #le mandamos la respuesta que lleva un rquest lleva el nombre del template
            #y se le pasa el contexto que es el form
    return render(request,'compras/compras.html', {'form':variable})
```

Comment: Estimada, si una respuesta te fue de ayuda, debes marcarla como aceptada, eso se hace al costado izquierdo de la misma respuesta, se debe de apretar el símbolo check (✓) saludos! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en la identación de tu código, en el `else`, en el caso de que el `method`, sea diferente a `POST`, ya que si fuera `GET`, así como está tu código `variable`, no tomaría ningún valor y al momento de retornarla, te sale el error.

```
def compras(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        variable=ComprasForm(request.POST)
        if variable.is_valid():
            variable.save() 
            return redirect('compras:compras')
        else: #este else te está dando el error
            variable=ComprasForm()
    return render(request,'compras/compras.html', {'form':variable})
```

Ya que como tienes tu código, estás preguntando que si es `POST` y `GET` a la vez, lo correcto sería que ese `else` esté a la altura del primer `if`:

```
def compras(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        variable=ComprasForm(request.POST)
        if variable.is_valid():
            variable.save() 
            return redirect('compras:compras')
    else: # en el caso que sea GET 
        variable=ComprasForm()
    return render(request,'compras/compras.html', {'form':variable})
```

En este caso  `variable`, va a tomar un valor siempre, siendo esta `POST` o no